# Static,buzzing sound when playing a sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm using a laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 and getting a buzzing noise when I play audio. You can hear it in this clip: [Example](https://streamable.com/y0dmd2)

I used to get static noises on all flash video players, back when I was running Windows and was able to fix it by installing another audio driver.

I always hear the noise at Twitch.tv; When I watch YouTube videos I hear it sometimes, but not always.

I hear the noise in Spotify but it is much less pronounced and sometimes goes away altogether. Often when I start playing music its all clean and after some minutes the buzzing starts again.

I checked alsamixer but when I slide the volume down sound is not audible.

In my research I found a thread that suggested that `tsched=0 /` would help, but running that didn't make a difference.

tried `pulseaudio -k` but pulseaudio wont restart again when i kill it

In alsamixer, chip and card is ;

`Card: HDA Intel PCH      Chip: Realtek ALC269VB`

Comment: I added some edits that I think clarify the question but I'm still a little confused about when you hear the buzzing and when you don't. Were you have the buzzing on this machine when you ran flash videos in Windows? Or on other  machines? What do you mean by "Twitch is the same"? What were you hoping `tsched` would do?

Comment: Keep in mind that some things that might seem obvious to you aren't obvious to everyone reading your question.

Comment: No i fixed all problems when i installed a realtek driver, I added "Twitch.com is the same" because in youtube there is  mostly no problem i thought it will give some idea to people try to help. btw i dont know what does tsched do lol, i just saw it on some thread and give it a try. I'm new in ubuntu so i wanted to give all information i have

Comment: Showing threads you actually read that led you solutions to try goes a long way. I'm adding some edits so you can see an example of how I recommend clarifying your question.

Comment: okey, thank you :)

Comment: It looks really good wow. Thank you